# Failed to fetch packages for python:2.7.14-stretch using docker

Tags: debian, docker

Recently started seeing this error. What can I do to avoid it?

Docker file

````
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install --force-yes nodejs

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt```


error 

``` > [3/6] RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install --force-yes nodejs:                                                                  
#6 0.422 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                             
#6 0.439 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                     
#6 0.463 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                               
#6 0.483 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release                                                                       
#6 0.646 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
#6 0.667 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#6 0.680 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#6 0.729 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
#6 0.756 Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
#6 0.789 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 0.824 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#6 0.843 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 0.855 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 0.882 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#6 0.913 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 0.942 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#6 0.974 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 0.998 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.001 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#6 1.019 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#6 1.030 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.037 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#6 1.056 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#6 1.085 Err:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.085   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.2.132 80]
#6 1.113 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
#6 1.195 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.357 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.370 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#6 1.385 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#6 1.550 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.711 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
#6 1.727 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#6 1.742 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#6 1.903 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 2.063 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
#6 2.078 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#6 2.093 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#6 2.272 Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 2.437 Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
#6 2.437   404  Not Found
#6 2.451 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
#6 2.464 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
#6 2.628 Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main arm64 Packages
#6 2.628   404  Not Found
#6 2.635 Reading package lists...
#6 2.647 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
#6 2.647 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#6 2.647 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#6 2.647 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
#6 2.647 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found
#6 2.647 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.2.132 80]
#6 2.647 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install --force-yes nodejs]: exit code: 100```
````